# Support for crawlspace beams

Tags: beam, crawlspace

Bought my house in 2018. The beam in crawlspace is supported with some rusted plates on top of concrete, possibly to fix sagging over the years. My floor feels bouncy and I believe I should have better support to reduce the bounce. Could you please advise what to replace the plates with.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does the steel beam support...joists?...spacing?...  What room is above the beam? How far is it to the next beam (or wall) on each side of the beam? How far does the steel beam span each direction?

Comment: What is the size of the floor joists (2X?) that run perpendicular to the beam and their span length? If the floor above the beam is flexing, "a bouncy floor", the problem may be that the floor joists are not big enough for the span. That said, those shims between the brick and the steel beam should have been steel not wood.

Comment: The kitchen and living room are above the crawlspace. I added a wide angle picture of the crawlspace in the post. The wall is 10 feet away on either side of the beam, and the beam itself is 20 feet long. 

The shims are rusted iron, I verified it. 

Joists are 2x8 and spaced 16 inches apart

Comment: Is that concrete above the I-beam? What is your subfloor material made of? A concrete slab or wood slats/plywood?

Comment: Tyler, the subfloor is wood slats / plywood

Answer (score 0):

I see no "steel plates" that support the beams. In fact the bottom flat plate is an integral part of the the I-Beam itself.

If you look at the attached enlarged view....

[image]

... you can see that the lower flat face of the I-Beam is actually supported on some wooden tapered wedges. These are in turn appearing to be sitting on some whiteish colored bricks. These could be fire bricks or even concrete bricks (it is hard to tell from the pictures).

The floor "bounce" that you are experiencing may very well be very slight deflections of the I-Beam itself. You could experiment with some temporary adjustable support posts under these I-Beams at mid span to see if that offers any significant change in the floor bounce that you experience.

Comment: Michael, those are definitely some iron plates that have rusted and look like wood, I touched to verify. I added a wide angle picture of the entire crawlspace.

Comment: That I beam is not moving ( enough for a human to feel ).